# jQuery Slider - can you have different colours on the bar?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

Am using the jQuery Slider option.

**JSFIDDLE**

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/1723/)

**Coloured Bar**

```
 $('.ui-widget-content').css('background','green');
```

So, I can colour the bar as above, which is fine but it is all one colour.

However, what I would like to achieve is different colours on the bar, so in this example.

The bar would be coloured where values are between 0 and 30, orange between 30 and 70 and green between 70 and 100.

The result would be a bar with red, orange and green that the slider moves over.

Is that possible?

**Answer provided using linear gradient is what I need but the client is using IE8.**

Comment: Would a background image work?

Comment: @J08691 - it would but due to the fact that the size of bar varies depending on screen size - I thought it would be easier trying to use css.

Comment: Well I meant a CSS background image. And it should scale to fit any screen that way as well.

Comment: @j08691 i was thinking `background-image` too but i ended up running into an issue with sizing the image to the bar. `background-size' isn't recognized in ie8 so the image would need to be exactly the right size for the bar -- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/teawd5dw/1/)

Comment: @JRulle - thanks for this, yes, IE8 is a problem :(

Comment: One alternative would be to change the whole background colour depending on the value of the slider - it's not quite what I was looking for though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a linear gradient in your background to achieve this:

```
$('.ui-widget-content').css('background','linear-gradient(to right, red 30%, orange 30%, orange 70%, green 70%, green 100%)');
```

Here is the browser support for linear gradients: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/teawd5dw/

Comment: @Homer_J I can't test on IE8, can you tell me if this works for you. It's, essentially, a clunky workaround. Instead of using a gradient background, it uses jQuery to insert several absolutely positioned divs over the slider. http://jsfiddle.net/uk6qLqcv/

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer however, as I feel it would suit the majority going forward.  However, can I ask you leave in your IE8 solution and I'll leave mine in as well for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Marcelo is actually far more elegant and exactly what I needed.  However, IE8 proved problematic and as that was the browser of choice for the client, I needed to find an alternative.

I've utilised the `stop` function and then used simple `if` statements.  It's not exactly how I wanted it but it works.

```
$("#slider").slider(
{
            value:50,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            step: 10,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
            },
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
                var num = ui.value;
                if(num <= 30){
                $('.ui-widget-content').css('background','red');
                }
                if(num > 30 || num < 70){
                $('.ui-widget-content').css('background','orange');
                }
                if(num >= 70){
                $('.ui-widget-content').css('background','green');
                }
            }
}
);

$( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
```

**JSFIDDLE**

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2580/)