# <pe:knob> is it possible to have 3 steps rather than only 2?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, xhtml

I need a knob to be coloured depending on 3 steps.
E.g.:

I have a percentage, and I want my knob to be coloured:

- red, if percentage le 50%
- orange, if percentage between 50 and 85
- green, if percentage le 100

So it'll be coloured with the 3 different colours, if my percentage is 95%.

I found nothing on the web, neither on Stack Overflow.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: If it's a read only value, you could opt to use http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/metergauge.xhtml

Comment: As an alternative you could use a slider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948262/jquery-slider-can-you-have-different-colours-on-the-bar